# How to Read German and French special characters using C#

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, desktop-application

I have been working on a small desktop application and some of my request I get back response in German and French. But I'm unable to read them and show the exact word in label. I have tried different Encoding to read this but all in vain or I'm not doing them correct.

Here is code snippet.

```
HttpWebRequest req = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( url );
req.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse res = ( HttpWebResponse )req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding( "iso-8859-1" ) );
```

I have also use but no luck

`Encoding.Default,true`, `Encoding.UTF-8`

Here is pic to show the response I got back.

[image]

Comment: Try `UTF-8` instead of `iso-8859-1`

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks, It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you read is most likely UTF8-encoded, so if you use that instead of ISO-8859-1 it should work.

However, you should not hardcode this since you might get data with different encodings from different URLs. Use the [`ContentEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the response instead of the hardcoded encoding.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly UTF-8 encoded text read as if it were ANSI or Latin-1.